# Button can't be clicked while keyboard is visible - react native

Tags: react-native

I have an textInput and a button. While the textInput is focused, the keyboard comes up but if you tap the button with keyboard visible, first the keyboard disappears and then only you can tap button. Why is it? How can I make it work so that the button can be tapped with keyboard visible? The apps developed in android studio (android native) can get the click listener with keyboard visible. But in react native, it is not working. If you tap anywhere but button, then the keyboard should disappear, isn't it? But if you tap on the button with keyboard visible, the btn should receive the listener. I'm testing it in android devices.

P.S you can try it here: https://snack.expo.io/@codebyte99/addcomponents

```
<TextInput
    placeholder={'Type smth'}
    style={[{ borderBottomColor: 'gray', borderBottomWidth: 1 }]}
/>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this._onPressOut(); }}>
  <Text>click here</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The scrollview contains a prop `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` which handles the keyboard tap behaviour inside a scrollview.

For your case give it as `<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>`

Here is a expo link [scrollview with keyboard](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/addcomponents)

Comment: [This comment on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10138#issuecomment-304656278) states that `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'` should be set on all parent `ScrollView`s: `the fix for me was that I had to set keyboardShouldPersistTaps on ALL scrollview ancestors of my Modal...
otherwise, if any ScrollView in your parent tree do the default keyboardShouldPersistTaps="none", the keyboard will be dismissed (in my case I want to prevent a dismiss).`

Comment: If you are using a `Flatlist` (which creates a `ScrollView` internally), you can use this option too.

Answer (score 18):

As an addition to @thakur-karthik answer:

It's very important to note that in the scrollview scenario, some oddity occurs when you have a scrollview in a react-native modal.

Just adding `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}` on the scrollview in the modal *alone* will not work.

If you have scrollviews in any ancestors, they must *also* have `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}` declared on their components

Answer (score 8):

FYI: If you're using [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view), you need to do it like this:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
```

Answer (score 2):

**ScrollView** or **Flatlist**

The scrollview and Flatlist contain a prop **keyboardShouldPersistTaps** which handles the keyboard tap behavior inside a Scrollview when the keyboard is visible.

> keyboardShouldPersistTaps= 'handled'

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stuck on this issue, ensure any parent `<KeyboardAwareScrollView` or `<ScrollView`s also have this attribute, not just the immediate parent component. In my case a component further up the tree was a `ScrollView`, and despite trying the very well-established fix, nothing was working. Adding `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` to that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use this attribute:

```
keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
```

Answer (score 1):

If some one using Bottom sheet. Fix it using: `BottomSheetScrollView` view and `keyboardShouldPersistTaps`

```
<BottomSheetScrollView
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
    ...
>
    {children}
</BottomSheetScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case keyboardShouldPersistTaps is not working you can add the style to the FlatList or scroll, work for me, Becouse keyboardShouldPersistTaps was not working properly

```
{zIndex:1000}
```